# what does 3rd parameter of public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot) do?

Tags: android, view, layoutparams

[According to android.developer.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29)

> `root`    Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if
>   attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of
>   LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if
>   attachToRoot is false.)
>
> `attachToRoot`     Whether the inflated hierarchy
>   should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used
>   to create the correct subclass of `LayoutParams` for the root view in
>   the XML.

What is this subclass of `LayoutParams`? What happens to the layout parameters of the `resource` mentioned in the function parameter?

I tried both combination of true and false as 3rd parameter, only difference seems to be whether the the `resource` is attached as child. The layout parameters for `resource` mentioned in its xml file, stay in effect in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does `public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)` really means ?**

It points to the layout resource you want to inflate. The second parameter is the root view of the hierarchy you are inflating the resource to attach to. When the third parameter is present, it governs whether or not the inflated view is attached to the supplied root after inflation.

The last two parameters that can cause a bit of confusion. With the two parameter version of this method, LayoutInflater will automatically attempt to attach the inflated view to the supplied root. However, the framework has a check in place that if you pass `null` for the root it bypasses this attempt to avoid an application crash.

In most cases it will throw an Exception later on if LayoutInflater is allowed to automatically attach the inflated view to the root.

**So why this ViewGroup is given if we are not supposed to attach to it?**

It turns out the parent view as a very important part of the inflation process because it is necessary in order to evaluate the LayoutParams declared in the root element of the XML being inflated. Passing nothing here is akin to telling the framework “Sorry because I don’t know what parent this view will be attached to actually”.

[reference](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/)

Comment: "in order to evaluate the LayoutParams declared in the root element of the XML being inflated" what evaluation is needed?

Comment: I think no evaluation is needed for this, they are suitable as it is when added to another layout as child.

Comment: Then why parent is needed, when we don't want to attach it?

Comment: Passing parent means It will inflate layout with the given parent, but won't attach it to the parent..

Comment: @q126y bro, is there any confusion still left in your mind ?

Comment: No, it is clear now. The answer is buggy implementation of layout inflator requires us to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If set to true then when your layout (resource) is inflated it will be automatically added to the view hierarchy of the `ViewGroup` specified in the 2nd parameter as a child. For example if the root parameter was a `LinearLayout` then your inflated view will be automatically added as a child of that view.

If it is set to false then your layout will be inflated but won't be attached to any other layout (so it won't be drawn, receive touch events etc).